# ideas for apps that show news headlines (what is such a feature called and what I should research to implement it)

Tags: java, android, feed

My friend wants an Android app in android that will show him news from various selected websites, about some particular topics (health, electronics, etc) and not main headline news. Now I assume the websites in question should provide some method for extracting their news for this to be possible, but I am not sure how I should go about starting to write to write this app. I'm pretty sure news websites probably have a way to pick out any and all news that they give out, but like I said, my app should be able to only get the news pertaining to some selected topics (like health or entertainment)

What is this feature called? How should I go about starting this? Any ideas for what keywordds to search for would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Tell your friend to install Feedly or some other news/rss reader app.

Comment: Many websites provide RSS feeds that do exactly what you want. And Android has plenty of RSS readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost, it sounds like you need a little more background information before you are going to be able to tackle something like this:

1. [RSS feeds with Java Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/RSSFeed/article.html)
2. [Documentation on using RSS](http://www.myjavatools.com/projects/v.1.4.2/xml/doc/com/myjavatools/xml/Rss.html) (For additional resources not provided above that may be of interest).
3. [Another resource with code examples](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/03/21/reading-news-with-sun-rss-utilities.html)

Those resources are provided assuming that you are tackling this project to get a better understanding of newsfeeds in Java programming language. If your friend is really looking for a newsreader that filters results as you described, it would be easier and more practical for both parties to download a few apps and try them out.

[Article on some of the best news readers for android.](http://lifehacker.com/the-best-news-reader-application-for-android-5807863)

Hope this is helpful to you and your friend.

Answer (score 1):

Dude you should follow some of the steps mentioned below to get news in your app:

1. Search through the web for some news sites that provide some RSS feeds .
2. Select the news genre like Top-Stories , Movies etc whatever you want int the RSS feeds menu.
3. A RSS feed page will open on selecting a specific genre , which consist of news related to the the genre.
4. There on that page , right click and view page source.
5. The Page source will start with  tags and then study the whole xml pattern , there's all the news within that page source.
6. Now all you need to do is make some internet calls from your app,do SAXparsing or XMLPullParsing whatever you want just to extract data from that page link.
7. Now display that data in your app in form of List or whatever view you want.

I hope this helps you buddy. :)